# Can I separate my aspx page as an external template to render it by jsrender?

Tags: asp.net, templating, jsrender

Can I separate my aspx page as a external template to render it by jsrender? I can't implement this because my aspx page contains server controls

Comment: so what is your question here ?

Comment: My question : how to separate the template which is contains server controls to external file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use templating tools such as:
Handlebars
Mustache
or JsRender
But you need to put only `runat="server"` option to the html objects

Comment: Thanks alot, but sorry do you mean I can't separate without replacing the server controls by html objects?

Comment: It means that you can do it. But i suggest to use handlebars, i have tested it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch an external template from the server, to use in JsRender, you can certainly fetch that from any kind of server page, or request.

In the second sample here: http://www.jsviews.com/#compiletmpl *"Sample: Registering a template from a markup string (fetched from the server in a text file)"* - a template is fetched from a server page - *.../person.txt*.

This  will work equally well if the server page is *...person.html*, or *...person.aspx* or a path using routes, or whatever.  However if it is an aspx page, you will not want to use the whole page as a JsRender template - since it will include things like `"<form method="post" ... onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"`. But you can certainly embed your template in the returned content, (and even have the embedded template be generated using server controls), then extract it from the full content before passing it to JsRender:

```
$.get("pathToAspxPage", function(value) {
  personTemplate = $.templates(value.slice(startOfEmbeddedTemplate, endOfEmbeddedTemplate));
  ...
```